# Stuck in grub while trying to reboot after deleting the Windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kernel

I removed my Windows partition since I haven't been using Windows for several months. I extended the Linux root to utilize the freed up space, following steps from two YouTube videos(https://youtu.be/SwsdqGEh2t8?si=751MnRwXKjaIVITE and  https://youtu.be/0HVX0kEC5NU?si=HLDxutL9CtbMq4ER). After rebooting to implement the new partitions, I find myself stuck in the GRUB terminal and unable to log in to Ubuntu.

I tried following different articles and YouTube videos to get out of this many of which asked me to find the Linux kernel and the RAM disk image, but I was not able to find them.

Grub:

[image]